# invalid value user input ask again to place into array

Tags: java, arrays

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int grade[] = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter your test score:");
    grade[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to make it so if the user input is below 0 or above 100 it will ask again. I'm very new to Java and this is the first language I'm learning. I would appreciate any pointers. Do I need to use a do-while loop instead of a for loop for this? Or do I implement an if statement into the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the input by putting an `if` block inside the `for` loop.

However, since your loop will only execute three times, you should change your increment condition only when user enters correct input or else not.
You also can use while loop here.

Here is some example code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) 
{
    System.out.println("Enter your test score:");
    
    if(grade[i] < 0 || grade > 100)
    {
         i--;
         continue;
    }
    grade[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

The `if` block will check that *if the input is outside boundaries, decrement `i` and restart the loop.*

Comment: I tried this and it made me do 2 inputs every time for some reason.

Comment: you can change this line  grade[i] = scanner.nextInt();   with  grade[i] = inputMarks;

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is, instead of incrementing i in loop, you can increase the value in if condition. Like below,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int grade[] = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < grade.length;) {
        System.out.println("Enter your test score:");
        int temp = scanner.nextInt();
        if (temp >= 0 && temp <= 100) {
            grade[i] = temp;
            i++;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid score");
        }

    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

This basically gets a input value from user, if the value is greater or equal to 0 && lesser or equal to 100,then adds it to the Array and increments the loop count(array index value we can call it), else, prints message asking for valid input.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shoving the validation logic somewhere within the loop, you could also write a small utility method which neatly asks for valid input, and continues to do so until the user finally inputs something valid:

```java
int promptInt(Scanner scanner, int min, int max, String errorMessage) {
    while (true) {
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        if (min <= input && input <= max) {
            return input;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

You could then simplify the loop:

```java
int grade[] = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter your test score:");
    grade[i] = promptInt(0, 100, "Please enter a valid number");
}
```